# virt-manager permission denied when trying to access .img file on zfs pool

Tags: zfs, libvirt

using fedora 25

I can create, but not access (i.e. vm's use) .img files sitting on my zfs pool

note: using zfs-fuse (regular zfs will not work on fedora). I was able to get this working using zfs-fuse on a prior implementation.

I tried nano /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

i.e. user = "root"; group = "root"

but still have an issue.  I've also tried chmod 777 as well as chmod o+x as well as chown to nobody:nobody and back again to root:root

[image]

Comment: found a solution: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1275 need to "setenforce 0", something to do with selinux.  Not sure why, any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: It is not correct that "regular zfs will not work on fedora".  Or perhaps I misunderstood the comment.  You can use kernel-based zfs on fedora - the zfs-on-linux project has a fedora package repository.  If you are referring to distributing kernel-based zfs, then there are potential license issues, but that does not preclude one from using zfs on their own linux system.